# Namespace implementation for google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing an application that requires namespacing in google app engine . I am thinking of using namespaces to allow a group of users see different data , however another global namespace should be available to enable seeing all the data stored by all the various user groups , This is my use case 
Company A signs up, creates a dynamic namespace named company-a.
Company B signs up, creates a dynamic namespace named company-b .

Now the client application(Mobile / Web) will need to fetch the data stored by Company A and Company B and display it . How do i accomplish this type of scenario with google app engine .
Do take note that the application is running on google cloud endpoints that handles all the datastore operations .

Comment: the normal way to do something like that would be to code something, deploy it to app engine, test it. If you have an issue with that, you come back to stack overflow and you ask a more precise question :). For now, maybe reading this would help? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy

Comment: Thanks i have read that , i'm here for more clarity to enable a standard implementation .

Comment: more clarity about what? the article explains what you have to use, complete with implementation examples....

Comment: My primary concern is not only  implementing the namespace but if its possible to get entities across the various namespaces

Answer (score 1):

Datastore namespaces are designed to provide strict [multitenancy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy). Therefore it is not possible to issue a cross-namespace query. If you'd like to provide mixed access, you have two possibilities:

1. When you are operating in the "global" namespace, you can issues one query per namespace. Then on the client you can join these together. You can dynamically get a list of your namespaces by issuing a query on the `"__namespace__"` kind. However, this would be inefficient if you have a lot of namespaces.
2. Implement your own version of namespace. You can add a property (for example `namespace`, or just `company`) to all of your models to indicate which company that Entity belongs to. On the page for "company-a", you filter all queries by `company = "company-a"`. Then in the "global" namespace (the client application), you issue the queries without a `company` set. This requires more diligence on your part, but is also more flexible.